# Oracle - Select distinct em apenas uma coluna

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela:

aluno1 - dado1 
aluno1 - dado2 
aluno2 - dado1 
aluno2 - dado2

E quero que minha query retorne:

aluno1 - dado1 (data + recente)
aluno2 - dado2 (data + recente)

Como faço para dar um distinct só no aluno com a data mais recente? Tentei [conforme essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983202/oracle-11g-sql-to-get-unique-values-in-one-column-of-a-multi-column-query), mas não tô acertando a sintaxe

```
   select *
   from (
        select ac.cod_matricula,
          he.cod_usuario_log,
          he.dt_atualiza_log,
          he.txt_ip_log,
          he.cod_usuario_log_del,
          he.dt_atualiza_log_del,
          RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ac.cod_matricula) rnk    
        from OW.HIST_HISTORICO HE, OW.ALUNO AC
        where ac.cod_aluno_curso = he.cod_aluno_curso
        and he.cod_usuario_log = '1234567'
        --and extract(YEAR from he.dt_atualiza_log) = 2018
        order by he.dt_atualiza_log desc )
   where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer retornar sempre a data mais recente da coluna dt_atualiza_log correto? Se for isto, não tem necessidade nenhuma do partition by, daria para resolver utilizando um agrupamento Max na data e adicionando os demais campos no group by.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo as instruções [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038193/select-row-with-most-recent-date-per-user), acredito que seja possível resolver desta forma:

```
SELECT rs.* FROM

  (SELECT
    ac.cod_matricula,
    he.cod_usuario_log,
    he.dt_atualiza_log,
    he.txt_ip_log,
    he.cod_usuario_log_del,
    he.dt_atualiza_log_del
  FROM
    OW.HIST_HISTORICO HE, OW.ALUNO AC
  WHERE
    ac.cod_aluno_curso = he.cod_aluno_curso
    and he.cod_usuario_log = '1234567') as rs

WHERE rs.dt_atualiza_log = (SELECT 
                              MAX(he.dt_atualiza_log)
                            FROM
                              OW.HIST_HISTORICO HE, OW.ALUNO AC
                            WHERE
                              ac.cod_aluno_curso = he.cod_aluno_curso
                              AND he.cod_usuario_log = '1234567'
                              AND ac.cod_matricula = rs.cod_matricula)
```

Não tive tempo de montar um dataset de exemplo para testar, caso tenha algum erro de sintaxe acredito que esteja simples de resolver e seguir a lógica apresentada na resposta citada. Lá também são apresentados outras alternativas, trouxe apenas a mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @Confundir disse no comentário, você pode simplesmente utilizar o agrupamento com o `Max()`, dessa maneira:

```
    select
      ac.cod_matricula,
      he.cod_usuario_log,
      max(he.dt_atualiza_log) dt_atualiza_log,
      he.txt_ip_log,
      he.cod_usuario_log_del,
      he.dt_atualiza_log_del
    from
      OW.HIST_HISTORICO HE, OW.ALUNO AC
    where
      ac.cod_aluno_curso = he.cod_aluno_curso
      and he.cod_usuario_log = '1234567'
    group by
      ac.cod_matricula,
      he.cod_usuario_log,
      he.txt_ip_log,
      he.cod_usuario_log_del,
      he.dt_atualiza_log_del
```

Comment: dessa forma ele pega os datas maiores, mas não seleciona apenas uma matrícula

Comment: Não consigo visualizar como estão dispostos os seus dados. Você não consegue fazer um [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) ou postar um exemplo de alguns dados em tabela na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se você estiver utilizando o Oracle 12c, existe uma função que foi incorporada que pode ajudar você nessa sua situação, em específico a função "FETCH FIRST n ROWS", neste [artigo](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/database-performance/noves-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-oracle-12c-3697686-ptb.html) é possível ver com mais detalhes o seu funcionamento e explicação de utilização.

Utilizando a função para o seu problema, seria algo do tipo:

```
select ac.cod_matricula,
       he.cod_usuario_log,
       he.dt_atualiza_log,
       he.txt_ip_log,
       he.cod_usuario_log_del,
       he.dt_atualiza_log_del
  from OW.hist_historico he, OW.aluno ac
 where ac.cod_aluno_curso = he.cod_aluno_curso
   and he.cod_usuario_log = '1234567'
 order by he.dt_atualiza_log desc fetch first 1 rows only
```

No caso você ordena primeiro pela data que você deseja e depois pede para exibir n linhas, que no seu caso seria 1.